# Star Wars Knights of the Old Republic Math Puzzle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

This question confuses me on how to reach a solution for it. In the game, a robot poses this question:

Droid K-X12d:
Puzzle - Battle Droid: Scanning memory nodes...
4 * 14 * 11-14 * 31-14 * 13-21-14 * ...?... * ...?...
Error: Descriptive number progression corrupted. 
To re-calibrate, determine the correct progression by describing the previous entry.

We're given a few answers to choose from but I actually want to know how this question is mathematically solved.

The answers are in a format such as 12-34-56-78 * 12-34-56-78

I know the answer which I'll leave in spoiler tags in case you want to work the solution before looking at the answer.

> 31-13-12-14 * 23-41-12-14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the "look and say" sequence. We start with
$4.$ There is "one four" so we then write
$14.$ Now there is "one one and one four" so we write
$11-14,$ and so on.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Answer (score 4):

You just have to go from left and right and compute the frequency of the digits that you encounter.

For example for $$13-21-14.$$

The first number that you encounter is $1$, there are three of them hence "three" $1$,

Followed by the next number $3$, which occur once, hence "one" $3$ and so on.